"Underlying network changed" error while trying to deploy in zksync Sepolia Testnet
Trying to deploy a contract on zksync sepolia testnet. My Metamask network is zksync sepolia testnet too. I got the following error:
Error: "underlying network changed (event=\"changed\", network={\"chainId\":300,\"name\":\"zkSync Sepolia Testnet\"}, detectedNetwork={\"name\":\"sepolia\",\"chainId\":11155111,\"ensAddress\":null}, c...

It seems while deploying, zksync Sepolia is automatically changing to Sepolia.
I'm trying to deploy using the zksync plug-in in Remix IDE.


Make sure that your ZKSYNC Plugin is activated and showing in the left menu bar.


Make sure that you're compiling and deploying the contract by selecting the activated ZKsync plugin option from the left menu.


Then, from the Environment selection, instead of the Remote Devnet (which is the by-default selection), you've to manually select the Wallet option.



It'll show a list of options, from which you can select MetaMask and connect your account.



Then, you can compile the contract that you want to deploy.


Finally, you can click on Deploy, which will pop-up the MetaMask for the corresponding transaction (showing the TxType as 113, you can refer to Transaction lifecycle doc of Zksync for more details).



Once the contract is deployed successfully, you can interact with the contract functions by expanding the Interact option.


And, you can also copy the deployed contract address and search the same on ZKsync Era Block Explorer as 0x341F4BCA101509ddbeC7720fA7B03A99b4C66C67.



